Best way for paying for fees when a user deploys a Safe
I want to let my users create a Safe and be able to cover those fees when deploying the Safe.
I see there are mainly two options to do it:

Via the Safe 4337 module
Using Gelato Relay

Question is, what's the recommended method?
Also, I see there are two options for Gelato.
1Balance and SynceFee. I am not sure what the difference is and which one to use.
Any help is very much appreciated!

The simplest way would be to use the 4337 module, as sponsoring for deployment transaction is not yet handled using Gelato. You can find an example implementation in the Safe x Passkeys tutorial code (full tutorial available here). The Safe object is created (using a passkey, but you can simply pass an address as an owner), and will be deployed after the mintNft() function is executed. This first transaction is batched with the deployment transaction and both are sponsored.
You can also follow the guide that you linked in your question, which should also cover that case.
Hope it helps! Best, Louis
